# Is there some method to decide folder to store index by name in elasticsearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

For example.
I have two folder,folder1 and folder2, to store the index. I want to specifies index1(index name) to store in folder1, and folder2 for index2.
Is there some method to support it???:)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can pass multiple data paths to ES, it will route/balance between them automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices are stored in different directories already. By default, `index1` is stored in `ES_HOME/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/index1` and `index2` is stored in `ES_HOME/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/index2`. So you can create a symbolic link `ES_HOME/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/index1` pointing to `folder1` and a symbolic link `ES_HOME/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/index2` pointing to `folder2`.

Starting with version 0.90.0.Beta1, Elasticsearch uses [a store distributor](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/store/distributor/Distributor.java) to decide which directory a file should allocated to. Distributors can be configured on per index basis, so it's possible to create a plugin with a distributor that will always allocate index in a particular directory.