# Retiring data from SSD to HDD

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We're currently comparing the ELK stack to Splunk and one of the places where Elasticsearch performs woefully worse is in data retention. Ideally we would like to **never** delete an index.

Our configuration is:

My current scenario is:

- 3 Elasticsearch data nodes

  - 64GB RAM, Dual CPU (16 cores), 2x 1TB SSD RAID0 & 2x4TB in RAID0 (x2)
  - 32GB RAM, Quad CPU (32 cores), 2x 512GB SSD in RAID0, 4x4TB HDD in RAID10

What I'm looking to do is write all indexes to the SSD's by default but after a certain period of time move the data to a slower array **without running dual nodes**

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: I know it's possible to [copy or move indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403624/moving-an-elasticsearch-index-of-one-node-in-a-machine-to-another-drive-of-the-s), and you can set multiple data paths for a node, but as far as I know it will always "stripe" data between them. I have seen some suggestions about using symlinks to map moved index folders to another drive (like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129121/is-there-some-method-to-decide-folder-to-store-index-by-name-in-elasticsearch)) -- but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This is not currently possible with ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do it - well, for the most part. Look at below blog post which describes it better than I can here

https://www.elastic.co/blog/hot-warm-architecture

Comment: Is this answer wrong? When I visited here, this answer has -1 vote. I up-voted because I thought this is a right answer.

Comment: Only took me two years to accept this answer, sorry. This is the closest to a correct answer - but does require multiple logical nodes if you still want to keep the indices on the same host.